# Test Javascript calls to api with jest

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, jestjs

I am trying to test the call to `github` `api` using `jest` to see if the results are returned (the aim of this is to test my unit testing skills). But for some reasons, my code works fine but still fails my test. My suspicion is that i most likely don't understand how to write these kind of test. Below is my code

```
const functions = {
    getUserRepo: async (username) => {
    const url = `https://api.github.com/users/${username}/repos`;
    console.log(url);
    let result = [];
    await axios.get(url)
        .then(function (response) {
            response.data.forEach(value => result.push(value.name));
            return result;
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            return error;
        });
    }
}
```

This code above returns the right results in an `array` format but fails the `test` below

```
describe('Check repos from git api', () => {
test('Should return user repos', async () => {
    await functions.getUserRepo('whitehox')
        .then((response) => {
            expect(response.data).toEqual([ '57','decafreelance','decases','eexport','exportchat','flisch', 'gitprac', 'itravelcentral', 'pollark', 'portfolio', 'startereit', 'talkative', 'team-portfolio'])
        })
    });
});
```

Please what is the issue with this `test` and how do i fix it?

Comment: You probably forget to return result at the end of function getUserRepo

Comment: It shows the right result when i `console.log(result)`. So i don't think thats the issue @edvardchen

Comment: Try `const result = await getUserRepo('whitehox'); console.log(result);` and you would understand what I mean

Comment: First you code example threw and `error` cause you can't use `await` in this case. Try running my code as a whole and see what you get. `console.log(result)` instead of `return result`. @edvardchen

Comment: @edvardchen you were right about returning the result at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things need to be fixed.

You need to return the `result` from your function.  It can be simplified to this:

```
const functions = {
  getUserRepo: (username) => {
    const url = `https://api.github.com/users/${username}/repos`;
    console.log(url);
    return axios.get(url)  // <= return the result
      .then(function (response) {
        return response.data.map(value => value.name);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        return error;
      });
  }
}
```

...which makes `response` the array so test it directly:

```
describe('Check repos from git api', () => {
  test('Should return user repos', async () => {
    await functions.getUserRepo('whitehox')
      .then(response => {
        // response **is** the array
        expect(response).toEqual(['57', 'decafreelance', 'decases', 'eexport', 'exportchat', 'flisch', 'gitprac', 'itravelcentral', 'pollark', 'portfolio', 'startereit', 'talkative', 'team-portfolio', 'YorubaIndigenous']);  // Success!
      })
  });
});
```

(...and there is also a new repo called `'YorubaIndigenous'`, I added it to the expected value).